# How do I view files and folders in a list?

Tags: nautilus

There is not an `Edit | Preferences` option.  How do I get the files to display in a list view with details, and not as icons?

Answer (score 17):

To change the default for **all folders** *, Open the file manager and when the window is active move the mouse pointer to the top left of the top panel and you will see:

[image: Nautilus toolbar options]

Select `Edit -> Preferences -> Views (tab) -> View new folders using` then select your preferred view type (in your case it would be 'List').

To change the default view for **just that folder**, select `View -> List` from the menu, or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

*Note that in the first step the default preferences will not be used for any folders you have manually changed view type on in the past. To reset this, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/164551/12864) then apply the new default preference.

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of Ubuntu you can click the list button on the taskbar:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In 12.04 and 12.10 (under the default Unity desktop environment), **hold down the** <kbd>Alt</kbd> **key for just a second**, and you'll see the options for Edit->Preferences and the rest (top left of the screen).

Maximization will also let you see the pull-down menus, but isn't necessary.  The handy shortcut to maximize your application or window is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> ("Up" is the "Up Arrow" key).  The same combo but with the down arrow reverses the maximization effect.

In Unity, hold down the Super or Windows key to see shortcuts.

**It's generally easiest**, though, to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to see a list view, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to go back to icons.

Answer (score 1):

Open your file manager then move your mouse to the left of the top panel
and select 'View' then 'List' (near the bottom) or try CTRL+2.

Comment: I agree with user44179's method. The quickest way to get to a list view in Nautilus (Ubuntu's default file manager) is with the keyboard shortcut CTRL+2. You can also use the menu method as Jacob Johan Edwards suggested.

Answer (score 1):

From a command line you can list what is in a directory with `ls -la`

For example

```
warren@min:~/workspace/crc8$ ls -la
total 52
drwxrwxr-x  4 warren warren  4096 Apr  3 10:41 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 warren warren  4096 May 22 13:39 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 warren warren 31048 Jun 10  2011 .cproject
drwxrwxr-x  3 warren warren  4096 Apr  3 11:22 Debug
-rw-r--r--  1 warren warren  2380 Jun 10  2011 .project
drwxrwxr-x  2 warren warren  4096 Apr  3 10:41 src
warren@min:~/workspace/crc8$
```

Its also possible to get a tree like view by installing **tree**

To install `sudo apt-get install tree`

Typical output.

```
warren@min:~/workspace/crc8$ tree
.
├── Debug
│   ├── crc8
│   ├── makefile
│   ├── objects.mk
│   ├── sources.mk
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── crc8.d
│   │   ├── crc8.o
│   │   └── subdir.mk
│   └── txt
└── src
    └── crc8.c

3 directories, 9 files
warren@min:~/workspace/crc8$
```

Answer (score 0):

In 13.04 "Raring Ringtail":

1. Open "Files" or just some folder like Documents, Music etc.
2. Move your mouse pointer to the top - left corner and click on Files -> Preferences. Or the new **smart way**: Press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key (do not hold it, just press for less than one second) to open [HUD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD) and start typing *Preferences*, select it and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
3. In the *Views* tab, set *View new folders using* to *List View*. Optional: For small screens I like to set the default zoom level for list view to 33%.
4. Close all folder windows and reopen them. Everything should be fine now.