# How to reset all per-folder view settings in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

As per title, how do I reset all custom view setting for all folders that I previously set a custom view mode (icon/list/compact) for? I made a change to the `Default View` setting in Preferences and I want old folders to use that new setting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To delete those previously saved (per-folder) view preferences, delete the files in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata` (Open your home folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files).

Next time you start Nautilus, all folders should use the view type you set in the preferences.

Comment: Seems to work for the Nautilus-derived file manager Nemo of Cinnamon Desktop (e.g. Linux Mint) too. Yes, I am intentionally throwing in those search keywords here.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install dconf-tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Open `dconf-editor` by typing it in the dash.
3. Then go to **org --> gnome --> nautilus --> preferences** and then change the value of `default folder viewer` to your desired settings. probable values are **icon_view** , **compact_view**, **list_view**.

[image]

See if the result is as expected.

Comment: This was the answer that I found most useful/straightforward, thanks!