# How to set visible columns default for the 'Files' file manager?

Tags: nautilus

I can't find the global settings to fix visible columns in the 'Files' file manager. I repeat: Global settings for the whole system thus NOT per directory.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 16):

For Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Bionic

1. Open Terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T
2. Install `dconf-tools`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
3. Open dconf-editor using `dconf-editor` command.
4. Go to `org/gnome/nautilus/list-view/default-visible-columns`. There you can edit the custom value field with the **name of the columns** you would like to be as the default view for all your folders.
5. Also, you can go to `org/gnome/nautilus/list-view/default-column-order` and set the default **order the columns** will appear as per your desire.

Comment: Oddly enough, this seems to work except for the `mime_type` column ("Detailed Type" as it shows up in the UI.)

Comment: This was the answer that I found most useful/straightforward, thanks!

Comment: Still working on Ubuntu 22.04. The possible names for the columns are `name`, `size`, `type`, `owner`, `group`, `permissions`, `detailed_type`, `where`, `date_modified_with_time`, `date_modified`, `date_accessed`, `date_created`, `recency`, `starred`.

Answer (score 12):

This works in ubuntu 21.10 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dconf-cli dconf-editor
```

And then open dconf-editor
and go to org gnome nautilus list-view

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted. It is the best (only) solution for Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: In case someone wants the name of the columns, from the nautalius project they are: ```{
    "name",
    "size",
    "type",
    "owner",
    "group",
    "permissions",
    "detailed_type",
    "where",
    "date_modified_with_time",
    "date_modified",
    "date_accessed",
    "date_created",
    "recency",
    "starred",
 
};``` also, in my case I also had to set the key in dconf as I didn't have it before using `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-visible-columns "['name', 'date_modified', 'type', 'size']"` which sets it with some default values.

Comment: Perfect for `22.04`.

Comment: Was the line `sudo add-apt-repository universe` neccessary?

Answer (score 9):

In `nautilus` (the 'Files' manager), open the <kbd>**Edit**</kbd> menu and select <kbd>**Preferences**</kbd>.

In the appearing configuration window, navigate to the <kbd>**List columns**</kbd> tab. You should see a list of checkboxes like the one in my screen shot below:

[image: Nautilus / Preferences / List columns]

Simply select your preferred default columns you want to see here.

---

However, if you ever manually changed the columns for a single folder only, that folder got its own configuration, which has a higher priority than the global defaults this method has set. Therefore it won't take effect in these directories.

You must reset the view settings for those directories manually using one of these methods:

- In the <kbd>**View**</kbd> menu, click <kbd>**Reset view to defaults**</kbd> to reset the current folder's view.
- Right-click on the column headlines of the current folder, then select <kbd>**Use defaults**</kbd>.
- To reset **all** folder-specific view settings **everywhere**, delete all files in `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`.

  You should do this from a terminal using the command

  ```
  rm ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*
  ```

  Then restart Nautilus (there's a daemon running in the background as well!) using the command

  ```
  nautilus -q ; nautilus -n & disown
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt effort however this is not the settings changing invisible/visible columns for the whole system but for the currently open directory. :) --- In the past I have been able to set the default setting but forgot how. So what I mean is how to set the default invisible/visible columns settings.

Comment: @user232365 See my edit. The method I described sets the default, but it gets overridden by the custom, folder-specific settings you made once.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I found out how to reset all view settings. It's described here: http://askubuntu.com/q/164551/367990. I also edited my answer.

Comment: That's it! Unfortunately, it makes the *question* a dupe. Not the answer however :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm No, the question is about how to modify the global default column settings and how to reset all folder-specific configurations to the global ones. The linked question only covers the second half.

Comment: @Matsmath I guess you could just search anything and then drag the columns around there, like you would do for any other single directory. Did you try that already?

Comment: @Matsmath Yes, just right-click the column headers while a search is open and enable all the columns you want to see. Just like you can do it in any other place. The settings dialog described in the answer is for the global default columns instead. You want to change those for a single location only, which can be done in the header's context menu.

Comment: @Matsmath Well, I tried it on 16.04. Maybe the functionality got (re)moved. I think you should ask a separate question, the comments here are not meant for extended discussions.

Comment: Option not there in 22.04 version. Please update answer accordingly

Comment: @Sagar my answer was posted 7 years ago and worked back then. I am not surprised that things have changed since, but I also don't have a setup and chance to check how it might work right now. If you figure anything out that isn't already listed in this or the other answers, please post a new answer to share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

**In 18.04 GUI method** Click <kbd>Files</kbd> then <kbd>Preferences</kbd> and you'll get this:

[image]

Check the boxes for the information you'd like to see in list view and close the Preferences dialog box.

Comment: This option does not exist for Ubuntu 22.02, so you should remove the "and beyond" from the title.

Comment: Yes, this option doesn't show up any more in 22.04. Please update your answer

Comment: @Sagar My apologies. Feel free to post your own answer